# How to assign an array of values to a range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating column headers for a bunch of columns. I would like to do them in one like below - but I couldn't get the syntax right. Can anyone help?

```
Range("AB1:AE1").Value = ("UnitPriceUSD","TotalCostUSD","UnitPrice", "TotalCost")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array("UnitPriceUSD", "TotalCostUSD", "UnitPrice", "TotalCost")

Range("AB1:AE1").Value = arr
```

Or even simpler:

```
Range("AB1:AE1").Value = Array("UnitPriceUSD", "TotalCostUSD", "UnitPrice", "TotalCost")
```

Comment: do I need to declare any array first? I just tried this and it works -     Range("AB1:AE1").Value = Array("UnitPriceUSD","TotalCostUSD","UnitPrice", "TotalCost").  Someone else posted this as an answer but deleted it.

Comment: Yes that seems to be enough, I always overcomplicate things.

Comment: Works for assigning across columns in a given row. But Range("A1:A2") = Array("a","b") assigns "a" to both A1 and A2.I assume the Array needs to be 2-dimensional, but Array only appears to support creation of 1D arrays.